# Sandbox allow same origin attribute for iframe not working in chrome,firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, iframe, sandbox

i have then following iframe within my https site,
I use the sandbox-"allow-same-origin" attribute in iframe to disable the mixed content warnings.

```
 <iframe scrolling="no" id='frame1' sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

It works for ie, but it keeps showing mixed content waring in firefox 23+ and chrome 30+

Any way i can supress these warnings in firefox and chrome ?